# Optimization in maple

Tags: maple

I optimized a function and I want to use the value.

The answer I got is [4.77011197468878567, [alpha = 1.43792823465135400]] and I want to use the alpha for plotting but I don't know how to extract it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ans := Optimization:-Minimize(...);

  ans := [4.77011197468878567, [alpha = 1.43792823465135400]];

ans[2];

   [alpha = 1.43792823465135400]
```

You can utilize that with the `eval` command, to evaluate-at-a-point (ie, substitute, mathematically).

```
eval(alpha, ans[2]);

        1.43792823465135400

expr := cos(alpha^2*x);

                     2
    expr := cos(alpha  x)

eval(expr, ans[2]);

     cos(2.067637609 x)
```